# Why doesnt [\n$] work while (\n|$) does?

Tags: regex, pcre

We have this string (without new line at the end):

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I want to match the entire string until new line `\n` or end `$` occurs.

- I firstly tried: `[\n$]` - didnt work.
- Then i tried `(\n|$)` - did work

**Question:** Why doesnt `[\n$]` match the string while `(\n|$)` does?

Comment: if you use the `m` ("multi-line") modifier for your regex, then the `$` will represent any end-of-line in the string, rather than the actual end of string. So you don't need to specify the `\n` at all.

Comment: Actually, to match the entire line you only have to do `^.*`.

Comment: "I want to match the entire string until new line" ... isn't that the whole line? :)

Comment: @Jack Ok :) You're right :) But I couldnt use this solution for some reason... because I needed to match end of line if it was in string. Only the end could be nothing or new line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because $ in a character class is seen as a literal

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it: a character class matches exactly one character. The end-of-line matched by `$` is an empty string. That's why and end-of-line cannot be matched by a character class.

(As a consequence, the only possible interpretation for `$` is the literal.)