# Regex: Matching single character with bracket or choice, why does bracket fail?

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have the following two cases where I want to find `matchme` from a string:

```
'>matchme but not this stuff'
'>matchme'
```

I am having trouble understanding the metacharacters work in regular expressions.

```
>>> re.search("(?<=\>)([^ ]*)(?= |$)", ">matchme but not this stuff").group(0)
'matchme'
>>> re.search("(?<=\>)([^ ]*)(?= |$)", ">matchme").group(0)
'matchme'
```

This I understand, but why does this fail:

```
>>> re.search("(?<=\>)([^ ]*)(?=[ $])", ">matchme").group(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

All I can think of is that in a bracket expression all metacharacters are treated as characters. I was under the impression that only `-` was the only metacharacter treated as a literal in brackets (granted under specific cases).

Are all metacharacters treated as literals in bracket expressions unless a specific meta case has been defined (i.e. `^` and `-`), or is this specific to python's `re` module?

Comment: you've answered your own question: "in a bracket expression all metacharacters are treated as characters", except for not (^) and range (-). Not specific to Python either.

Comment: even the range operator (-) is treated as a character in a bracket expression if it appears as the last character (i.e. just before the right bracket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.search("(?<=\>)([^ ]*)(?=[ $])", ">matchme").group(0)
```

This doesn't work because, in character class `$` is no more a special character but a literal character. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887354/why-doesnt-n-work-while-n-does/16887365#16887365)

The only characters that need to be escaped in a character class are: `^ ] -`

`^` need to be escaped only if it is at the first position in the character class.
`]` need to be escaped except if it is at the first position or immediatly after `^` *(if `^` is at the first position.)*
`-` need to be escaped except if it is at the first position or immediatly after `^` or at the end of the class.

This will work:

```
re.search("(?<=>)([^ ]*)(?= |$)", ">matchme").group(0)
```

note: no need to escape `>` that is **not** a special character.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is a literal when you put it in brackets; it is not a metacharacter in that context. So, `(?=[ $])` only matches if the last word (defined by `([^ ]*)` above) is followed by a space or a literal `$`, which isn't true in your sample texts.